# Empty basket after product was added?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

Recently I've met this problem, looking for solution, seems like a cache/cookies problem. Customers often have this issue and after click "Add to cart/basket".

Magento displays message "Shopping Basket is Empty"

Any ideas what can cause this issue ?

Comment: If tge user is logged in, prior to add to cart, do they get logged out?  This will define if issue is loss of session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Products are not properly added to the cart. Without more information we cannot tell what's causing the problem.

Follow these steps to determine what went wrong:

1. Use Inspector to see if the `add/` AJAX request returns any errors in the response.
2. Make sure the cookie domain and base_urls are correctly configured.

Do you have a clean Magento install? Or do you have any modules installed that might affect this behavior?

Comment: Definitely it must be related to the (full page) cache. We just turned it off and problem gone but if so, I must do something with FPC, it helps a lot. Page load time is much much shorter.

Comment: @Roberta Don't use fpc on cart / checkout. If those have slow page load times your use of fpc is just masking an underlaying problem.

Comment: Can I exclude cart from being FPC'ing ?

Comment: Depends on what fpc you are using. Enterprise magento? Or some 3rd party. In all cases rtfm ;)